# How to save settings as default in MS PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

I am trying to save MS PowerPoint settings so that every time that I open a new document it has those same settings. I am particularly (and, to be honest, only) interested in the embedding fonts check box that can be accessed through:

1. Click the **file** tab.
2. Click **options** near the bottom left of the window.
3. Select the **save** tab.
4. Under **preserve fidelity when sharing this presentation** select **embed fonts in the file** check box.

Somewhy, even if I check that box and save the document. If I create a new document, it is unmarked. I want it to be as default marked. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a presentation-level option rather than application-level; in other words, it's saved with each presentation. You *could* set the option, save a blank presentation with other formatting set to your preferences, then open the presentation, save it to a new file name to begin a new presentation.

Comment: Have you tried to use Slide Master? More details, you can refer to "[Change the default font in PowerPoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-default-font-in-powerpoint-8e93c947-c160-4310-8070-afea7da78c33)"